# How to listen to device shake in flutter app when it's at background?

Tags: flutter, notifications, background-process, sensors

I would like to send a notification whenever the users shake the device even when the flutter app is in the background, it works for a couple of minutes after the user sends the app to background but after sometime it stops responding and you have to reopen the app, Are there any ways to cope with this ? I tried changing the settings on the android device I'm using to disable putting this app to sleep but it doesn't seem to work, also tried locking the app in the recents didn't make a difference. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use native codes for this. I think for background-process, it is smoother. You look for more details : https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels